# ReSharper check unchanged files

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Not sure if SO is the correct place for this kind of question.

I'm currently using `Visual Studio 2015 Professional` and `ReSharper Ultimate` in it's latest version.
However, when closing my project (all files are checked and without any errors) and reopen it directly after it, `ReSharper` scans ~250 files. 
The number of files that are checked changes from start to start like some kind of random.

Question is, why `ReSharper` thinks those files need to be rechecked even if they don't changed. Could it be related to my local settings?

Comment: I had the same problem with ReSharper 9.2, so I downgraded to 9.1.3 and problem gone, but a week ago I updated my ReSharper to 10.0 and got the that problem again. It scans our solution (pretty big one) like 5-10 minutes, and until it stops I can't work at all. Really annoying.

Comment: Sounds like a bug if it does it in 9.2+ and not in 9.1.3. Could you [raise an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=), please?